# Why does $a≤b{\implies}a=b∧a<b$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $≤$ be a relation on set $A$ such that $≤$ is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric.

Let $<$ be a relation on set $A$ such that $<$ is asymmetric, antireflexive and transitive.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two different elements of $A$.
Why is it the case that if $a≤b$, then either $a=b$ or $a<b$? Why can't it be neither?

Comment: It should be $a\le b\implies ((a=b)\lor (a<b))$.

Comment: It can be neither. The way you put it, there's no relation between $<$ and $\leq$.

Comment: If it can be neither, why do I often see proofs, which first suppose that $a≤b$, show that $a<b$ is false and conclude that $a=b$?

Comment: @user285146 Because usually, and by definition, $a\leq b \iff (a<b\lor a=b)$. But you've mentioned no such assumption.

Comment: What's an example of such a thing? Where $A$ is totally ordered and $a≤b$, but both $a<b$ and $a=b$ are false, using my definitions?

Comment: @user285146 What's supposed to be totally ordered: $(A,\leq)$ or $(A,<)$?

Comment: @user236182 Apologies and thanks.

Comment: Since you aren't talking about the order, it'd be clearer is you used different less misleading symbols.  Why is that a R b implies a S b or a = b if R is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric and asymmetric, antireflexive and transitive.

Comment: @Git Gud: both ones.

Comment: @user285146 Let $A=\{1,2\}$, $\leq=\{(1,1), (2,2),(1,2)\}$ and $<=\{(2,1)\}$.Then $1\leq 2$ and you have neither $1<2$, nor $1=2$.

Comment: Why does $<={\{(2,1)}\}$? Shouldn't it be ${\{(1,2)}\}$?

Comment: @user285146 Because I defined $<$ so. The only restriction you've given is that $<$ must be an asymmetric and transitive and it is. You're missing the point I've made in my first comment and which fleablood reinforced on his: the way you put it there's absolutely no relation between $\leq$ and $<$. Perhaps you want to say that $\leq$ and $<$ and "associated" as intended in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_total_order) link?

Comment: Define "<" to mean "greater than" and define "$\le$" to mean "$\le$".  Then $0 \le 1$ but $0 \ne 1$ and $0 \not < 1$.

Comment: What's with the definition of $<$ one can see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictOrder.html or here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Strict_Ordering then?

Comment: You are being very unclear.  Are you asking about the symbols as the are commonly used for order (in which case "$\le \implies < OR =$" because that is the *definition") or are you asking for abstract relations that satisfying refl, sym, and transitive properties (in which case your statement is simply false)?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, $<$ means two things: one is relation $R{\subset}≤:R≠=$ and the second is any relation which is antireflexive, transitive and asymmetric. Why don't we use two symbols to discern these two things?

Comment: Also, when we define $<$ as $R⊂≤:R≠=$ (as in the Wikipedia link), how do we get transitivity?

Comment: You tell us! You are the one who is trying to redefine the symbols.  No, the symbols do *not* mean two different things at once.  *YOU* said "let $\le $ be a relation" so *YOU* are the one who made the declaration.  It is true that "\le" is *a* reflexive, trans, etc. relation but it isn't the only one.  Nor is it being refl.  etc. enough to define it.  So when you say "let $\le $ be..." we have to conclude we are redefining it.  If you said "let $\le$ be a pink elephant" I would have redefined it as a pink elephant.

Comment: Okay, I think I see your confusion.  In the links you quoted the relation "$\le $" is derived and defined from the relation "<".  In your OP you defined them *separately* and independantly.  As unrelated relations you statement isn't true at all.  But as related relations "$\le $" is defined to mean the relation a <b OR a = b.  That is NOT a result of it being a ref,trans,asymmetric relation.  That is the *definition*.  That it is refl, trans, asymm is the *result* of the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Let a and b be integers.  Let a $\le$ b be defined as a | b thats reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric.

Let a < b be such that a is strictly larger than b.  That's not reflexive , it's assymetric , and it's transitive.

Now  $2 |4$ but $2 \ne 4$ and 2 is not strictly larger than 4 either  so your statement is simply not true.

===

Unless you actually meant $\le$ to mean the standard "less than OR equal" and < to mean "less than"...

In which case "less than OR equal" means "less than" or "equal" because that's the definition!!!!

Comment: I find your answer incomprehensible and I am stunned that it got 3 upvotes. "Let $a \le b$ be defined as a | b" what does that even mean?!

Comment: It means let the symbol "$\le $" represent the relationship "a divides b".  That relationship is reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric.   Reread the OP.  S/he was declaring "$le$" and"<" as unspecified relationships.  The OP claimed reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric implies either equality or a transitive, anti reflexive, asymmetric relation.  I provided a counter example.  It was a very strange and very false claim.

Answer (score 0):

The $\vee$ symbol means OR and the $\wedge$ symbol means AND.

Remember that $\wedge$ looks like $\cap$ which means "In this set AND in that set"

On the other hand $\vee$ looks like $\cup$ which means "In this set OR in that set".

Or you could remember that $\wedge$ looks like the A from "And".

You have written $(a≤b){\implies}(a=b)∧(a<b)$

That means $(a \le b) \implies (a=b$ AND $a < b )$.

The second part of that cannot be true because if $a$ is equal to $b$ then $a$ cannot be less than $b$.

However if we wrote $(a \le b) \implies (a=b$ OR $a < b )$ then that would be true.

After all, what does $a \le b$ mean if not "$a$ is less than or equal to $b$"?

Comment: Also $ \land $ looks like an 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand you confusion better.

The linked page defines a "strict order" relation.  The most well known strict order is "less than" where a is "less than" b iff b-a is positive.  But a strict order can be any relationship that is irreflexive, asymmetric, and transitive.  Other possible strict orders could be "greater than"; a is "greater than" b iff a -b is negative.  Another is "is a proper integer divisor of".

Abstractly, we can use any such relationship to order a set.  And abstractly we can use the symbol "<" the indicate this strict order.  If we use this symbol we must define what we mean.

Now a strict order can have an additional charactoristics of being "total".  That means for any two non-equal elements a and b, a and b *must* be related either a < b or  b < a.   "less than" is a total relation.  "Is a proper factor of" is not.  Either a is less than b or b is less than a (or the are equal).  "Less than" us a total order.  "Is a factor of" is not.  It's possible for two different integers to have neither be a factor of the other.

Then there is the definition of a "partial order".  A *partial* order is a relationship that *is* reflexive.  It is antisymmetric (not assymetric).  And it is transitive. "Less than or equal to" and "divides (and could be equal)" are two examples of partial orders.

Now an arbitrary strict order such as "less than" and an arbitrary partial order such as "divides" don't need to have *anything* in commom.

BUT this is your contention.  You can take any total order "<" and *define* a partial order "$\le $" by *defining*  a $\le $ b iff either a < b or a = b.  Example:  if I defined "<" to be the *strict* order "is a proper factor of", I can define the *partial* order "$\le $" as "is a proper factor or is equal to".

And I can take a partial order "$\le $" and define a strict order by *defining* a < b iff a $\le$ b and a $\ne $ b.

But if I *do* define theses partial and strict orders, I define them in terms of each other.  I can not say if R is a strict order and S is a totally *unrelated* partial order than if a S b but a $\ne$ then a R b.  That'd be simply nutty.

But if "$\le $" was *defined* to mean "either < or =", then I *could* conclude if a $\le $ b and a $\ne $ b then a < b.  Because that was the definition.